# How to check if any of 2 possible keys is pressed with ConsoleKeyInfo?

Tags: c#, console-application

I encountered a pretty dumb problem with ConsoleKeyInfo. I want do check if "1" is entered using either numpad or regular top numeric keys.

```
 ConsoleKeyInfo keyPressed;
 keyPressed = Console.ReadKey();
 if (keyPressed = ConsoleKey.D1 || keyPressed = ConsoleKey.NumPad1)
 { }
```

And for some reason I cant use "||" operator. Is it possible to somehow check it within 1 if loop without using `Console.ReadLine();` and forcing user to press enter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to [compare](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) with `==` instead of `=`.
 Otherwise you're trying to assigning the value.

And you have to compare the [Key](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.key(v=vs.110).aspx) property of `ConsoleKeyInfo` which holds the `ConsoleKey` enum.

So your `if` should look like:

```
if (keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.D1 || keyPressed.Key == ConsoleKey.NumPad1)
```